# Issue with arabic language using itextsharp vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, itext, render

I am using `iTextSharp` to convert `HTML to pdf` that has `arabic` and `english characters`,. I was able to show the English characters, but no luck with the arabic ones. I am using below code

```
        Dim bf As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\windows\fonts\arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, True)
        Using sw As StringWriter = New StringWriter()
            Using hw As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
                Me.Page.RenderControl(hw)
                Dim sr As StringReader = New StringReader(sw.ToString())
                Dim pdfDoc As Document = New Document(PageSize.A4, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F, 0.0F)
                Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream)
                pdfDoc.Open()
                Dim font As New iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL)
                XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr)
                pdfDoc.Close()
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
                Response.Write(pdfDoc)
                Response.End()
            End Using
        End Using
```

Comment: Thanks but i am using VB.NET language not C# so please help me with solution in VB.NET

Comment: You will find relevant examples using C#. You can use an online tool such as [ICSharpCode Converter](https://codeconverter.icsharpcode.net/) to do most of the conversion - sometimes there are some parts of code that need to be adjusted by hand.

Comment: I think you would want to attach the original HTML so that people can reproduce your problem. Also, have you tried with iText 7? iText 5 is no longer maintained except for security fixes